# Html textbox without model in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I just moved to Yii2. How to make text box like this:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'xxx') ?>
```

but without using any model?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `yii\helpers\Html` and
Try something like,

```
<?= Html::textInput('xxx', value, options[]); ?>
```

[textInput()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#textInput%28%29-detail)

Answer (score 7):

I would add a label and the `form-control` Bootstrap class:

```
<?= Html::label('Person', 'xxx') ?>
<?= Html::textInput('xxx', value, ['class' => 'form-control']) ?>
```

Comment: how to make them inline?